# It took me overnight to solve that problem!

Tags: word-usage

do you think the following sentences are correct? And if not why?

'It took me overnight to solve that problem!'

'Her work took overnight to be finished.'

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your sentences are *syntactically* correct, however *idiomatically* you cannot use overnight as a noun. It is an adverb or adjective.

You can just use **all night**:

- It took me **all night** to solve that problem!'
- She took **all night** to finish the work.'

---

Overnight is used as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overnight) suggest

- He stayed overnight and went home the next day.
- Let the paint dry overnight.
- The novel made her famous overnight.

Adjective

- They went on an overnight bus trip

You do something all night, something happens overnight

Comment: Okay, but the thing is, why? Why should I use all night instead? What's my case exactly?

Comment: It is not idiomatically correct. You should not use overnight in your examples. I assume it is a passive vs active thing. You do something all night, something happens overnight

Comment: Look at the definition I posted. Something that happens during the night or happens very suddenly - in one night instead of several days/months

Comment: @AnneR I suppose it is because we use "overnight" as a specific time, rather than a time duration. Equally you couldn't say "It took me Wednesday to solve the problem". You would need to say "It took me all Wednesday/part of Wednesday to solve the problem". Similarly one needs to say "It took me all night...", though I appreciate that it has a slightly different meaning to "overnight". Perhaps you could say something like "It was a problem which I could only solve overnight". Though informally no one would object to your first sentence.

Comment: @AnneR As mpjungjan says, it is idiomatic to use "overnight" as an adverb or an adjective. It's not idiomatic to use "overnight" as a noun (as far as I know). But in a context like "It took me X to solve the problem", the sentence works syntactically only if X is a noun or noun phrase. "It took me an overnight session..." is OK; "it took me overnight..." is not.

Comment: @WS2 _It was a problem which I could only solve overnight_ is a good suggestion, but even that does not convey if they worked all night or just had to do it during the night because they are vampires or the problem only occurs at night :)

Comment: @mplungjan Correct. But the ambiguity is inherent in the word "overnight". One could equally say "It is an overnight issue" - meaning it will not be resolved until the following day. But it supplies no further explanation as to why.

Comment: @mplungjan, if a sentence has something that cannot be used as a noun in a position that calls for a noun, is it really syntactically correct?

Answer (score 1):

**The essential problem here is that "take" is a transitive verb, and the OP's sentences are attempting to use "overnight", which normally works as an adverb, as the direct object.**

If you insert a direct object into the sentence, "overnight" returns to the role of an adverb, and is ok.

E.g *It took me two hours overnight to solve the puzzle*. *Her work took time overnight to be finished*.

"Overnight" works perfectly well with an intransitive verb which will take an adjective but not a direct object. e.g. **They stayed overnight**.

Comment: That is the explanation of my gut feeling ;)

Comment: _Can_ a measure phrase (two hours) be a DO? I remember there being a bunfight about whether 'It costs $3' (can't find the pound sign) has a DO.

Comment: Well if the £3 isn't a direct object - what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct. They are merely unidiomatic.

The [OED](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/overnight) has the most extensive set of example sentences to support their definitions. The term 'overnight' as you use it is an adverb. Its meaning is given as "For the duration of a night." It's most often used with the verb 'stay', as in "stay overnight".

'Take' is a verb just as 'stay' is. If you can say "stay overnight" there's no reason why you can't say "take overnight". It might sound odd to many people, and even unacceptable to the staid. But no one can say it's wrong.

Whether you choose to follow idiom or not is a matter of style. Personally, I say go for it. Language is enriched by those who venture past the limits of prosaicness.

Comment: (1)The alleged link to the OED goes to Lexico. not the OED. (2) The OED gives "A. adv. *1. During or in the course of the night;*" and "'It took me *during or in the course of the night* to solve that problem!' does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> It took me overnight to solve that problem!'
>
> 'Her work took overnight to be finished.'

Both sentences are incorrect *in the way that you are using the word "correct"*, which I take to be "properly expressed".

Overnight is an adverb (*I worked on it overnight*) or an adjective (*The overnight train left at 11pm.*) You are attempting to use "Overnight" as a noun (the object of "take"), e.g. it took an hour to finish.

I advise against non-native speakers using strange constructions: in native speakers these are sometimes seen as "innovative" - in non-native speakers they are seen as mistakes.

Comment: This is not a matter of native vs. non-native, it's a matter of having a good understanding of the language or not. There are many native speakers how make more mistakes than some non-native speakers. You just need a very good understanding of the language to judge whether something is "innovative". Or to be able to believably mock Trumpisms and Bushisms.

Comment: @Greybeard: I agree with you.  There is a difference between "It took me two days" and "It took overnight...". Two days - is a noun; but 'overnight' is an adverb. Or, her work took overnight is like, 'Her work took beautifully, intentionally, etc.'